# Terraform vsphere provisioner: adding more than 1 network

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I have the following Terraform config

```
data "vsphere_network" "net1" {
  name          = "somenetwork"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_network" "net2" {
  name          = "somothernetwork"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
```

In my vsphere_virtual_machine resource I have the following:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {

 network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.net1.id
    adapter_type = "vmxnet3"
  }

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.net2.id
    adapter_type = "vmxnet3"
  }
```

Then in customization I have:

```
 network_interface {
  ipv4_address = "192.168.102.87"
  ipv4_netmask = 24
  dns_domain = var.dns_domain
  dns_server_list = var.dns_server_list
}

network_interface {
  ipv4_address = "10.3.1.19"
  ipv4_netmask = 24
}
```

But when I run the apply I get a 500 error from the vcenter.

```
Error: POST https://cloud9.lab.yolo.com/rest/com/vmware/vcenter/ovf/library-item/id:937fe71e-1b83-4e11-8097-b5b8e91cc317?~action=deploy: 500 Server Error

  on main.tf line 70, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
  70: resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
```

If I remove the second network the server deploys fine.
TY
Ted

Comment: Terraform and vsphere provider versions


Terraform v0.14.5
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vsphere v1.24.3

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional information to the question, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and found the solution here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/1469

Try to add the `ovf_mapping` parameter to each `network_interface` block.

For example:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ... 
  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    ovf_mapping = "ens192"
  }
  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    ovf_mapping = "ens224"
  }
  ...
}
```